# свайп в окне эмулятора Android через winapi

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Имею эмулятор BlueStacks.
Цель: написать простого бота, который в окне эмулятора нажимает на определенные области экрана эмулируя тапы, а также свайпает окно, когда нужно. Поскольку в winapi я не силен, по всей видимости, что-то просто упускаю. Моя логика следующая:

- С помощью EnumWindows пройтись по всем родительским окнам и найти
  окно с заголовком "BlueStacks"
- С помощью EnumChildWindows пройтись по всем найденным экземплярам родительских окно и найти дочерние окна.
- Перебрать дочерние окна (благо, их не много) и проверить какие откликаются на отправку им сообщений WM_LBUTTONDOWN в конкретной    клиентской области, содержащей интерактивный элемент. В моем случае,
  интерактивная область должна "замерцать" если нажать на ней мышкой и
  не отпускать ее.
- Запомнить на будущее класс найденного "отзывчивого" дочернего окна и начать работать с ним.

Напосредственная работа с окном:

Кликнуть мышкой в нужном месте.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct WINDOWINFO
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public RECT rcWindow;
            public RECT rcClient;
            public uint dwStyle;
            public uint swExStyle;
            public uint dwWindowStatus;
            public uint cxWindowBorders;
            public uint cyWindowBorders;
            public ushort atomWindowType;
            public ushort wCreatorVersion;
            public string sTitle;
            public int Width;
            public int Height;
            public HWND hWnd;

            public WINDOWINFO(Boolean ? filler) : this ()
            {
                cbSize = (int)(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWINFO)));
            }
        }
```

.....

```
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
 BringWindowToTop(currentChildWindow.hWnd);
 ShowWindow(currentChildWindow.hWnd, (int)SW.SW_SHOW);
 SetForegroundWindow(currentChildWindow.hWnd);
 this.Cursor  = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
 //сWindow - переменная для отладки дальнейших массовых манипуляций с окнами
 cWindow = currentChildWindow;
 Cursor.Position = new Point(cWindow.rcWindow.Left + 70, cWindow.rcWindow.Top + 370);
 SendMessage(cWindow.hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, MK_NONE, MakeLParam(new Point(cWindow.rcWindow.Left + 70, cWindow.rcWindow.Top + 370)));
 SendMessage(cWindow.hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON | MK_NONE, MakeLParam(new Point(cWindow.rcWindow.Left + 70, cWindow.rcWindow.Top + 370)));
```

Т.е. я создаю курсор, перемещаю его в нужную точку в окне.
Затем отправляю событие окну WM_MOUSEMOVE и следом WM_LBUTTONDOWN

И Это работает! Если отправить WM_LBUTTONUP - тоже сработает.
Но, ни в какую не работает свайп.
Я думал, свайп можно сделать совсем просто, как это происходит вживую с мышкой:

1. Зажать левую кнопку мыши
2. Провести мышкой по экрану в пределах окна
3. Отпустить мышку

Сделал так (продолжение предыдущего кода с нажатой клавишей):

```
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{ 
   Cursor.Position = new Point(cWindow.rcWindow.Left + 70 + x, cWindow.rcWindow.Top + 370);
   SendMessage(cWindow.hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, MK_NONE, MakeLParam(new Point(cWindow.rcWindow.Left + 70 + x, cWindow.rcWindow.Top + 370)));
   Thread.Sleep(15);
}
SendMessage(cWindow.hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_NONE, MakeLParam(new Point(cWindow.rcWindow.Left + 170, cWindow.rcWindow.Top + 370)));
```

Это не работает! По мерцанию элемента в окне видно, что окно приняло событие WM_LBUTTONDOWN
Затем я вижу, что мышь двигается по игровому окну по горизонтали.
Затем срабатывает WM_LBUTTONUP и мерцание интерактивного объекта в окне исчезает. Но свайп не работает. Мышь просто скользит по окну и всё.
Я понимаю, что накрутил лишнего и, возможно, смотрю вообще не туда. Очень прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: В принципе верно, но только в принципе. У эмулятора будет ворох под-окон, в том числе и у конкретной игры. Инпут с мышью, тяжкая задача, его надо реализовывать по схеме 'на заднем плане', иначе на компьютер можно только смотреть.. есть еще куча нюансов с эму. Рекомендую Memu вместо BlueStack, он легче и устройство-иерархия окон у него более понятная, там прописаны соответствующие классы у окон.

Answer (score 1):

Ларчик открывался намного проще. PostMessage для событий мыши, вместо SendMessage